# Switching GCP accounts and contexts with gcloud and kubectl is not working

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud, kubectl

I have 2 gmail accounts, each account is associated with 2 separate GCP accounts.  To switch accounts from the command line, I've been using both of these commands for the past 2 weeks or so:

```
$ gcloud config configurations activate ACCT_NAME
$ kubectl config set-context CONTEXT
```

Note: I also have been using 'kubectx' which makes switching contexts a bit easier than using 'kubectl config set-context'; basically its a bit less typing.  Both 'kubectl config set-context' and 'kubect' have worked in the past (I think).

It seems like this approach has been working fine until this morning.  I tried switching from context A to context B, but now I'm getting errors like this:

```
$ kubectl get pods -A                                             
Error from server (Forbidden): pods is forbidden: User "<my_email_address>" cannot list resource "pods" in API group "" at the cluster scope: Required "container.pods.list" permission.
```

The email address shown is for context A, not context B.  I checked the following commands to verify the current (or active) context and email accounts are correct:

```
$ kubectl config current-context
$ gcloud config configurations list
```

So the current contexts, accounts, and associated email addresses are correct.  I'm not clear why kubectl is still trying to access the GKE with the email account from context A (not context B).

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 17):

So I had posted this question a couple weeks ago:

https://serverfault.com/questions/997220/kubectl-not-showing-new-context-created-in-gcp

For whatever reason, I had to rerun this command to get things working again:

```
$ gcloud container clusters get-credentials NAME
```

Note: you can get the cluster name from this command 'gcloud container clusters list'

I have no idea why I had to re-run get-credentials.  I don't believe my credentials changed; this took me a while to figure out.

Comment: did you find any solution to do this seamlessly? i've tried this and it's working but the additional step seems tedious for me

Comment: @Teguh Sorry, nothing new to add (yet)

Comment: This has affected me for a about a year (at least, that's when I noticed it first) too. I often switch between gcloud accounts during and after work. 
I'm currently using the workaround where I re-run the gcloud command to get the context again each time I switch accounts. Quite annoying.

Comment: yeah, have to do it each time when I sign in with a new credentials