# Is there a better workflow for switching accounts with gcloud and kubectl?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, kubectl

I have several gcloud accounts and thus different kubernetes' contexts.

I find myself frequently switching between these using:

```
$ gcloud config configurations activate ACCOUNT
$ kubectl config set-context CONTEXT
```

or alternatively

```
$ gcloud config configurations activate ACCOUNT
$ kubectx CONTEXT
```

(for kubectx see https://github.com/ahmetb/kubectx)

This feels like a lot of typing.  Also it also seems like if you switch gcloud accounts, that it could intuitively switch the contexts (each k8s context maps to a gcloud account).

I'm curious to see other people's workflows.  Or is there a more efficient 
or conventional workflow?

---

The reason I need to switch both account and context is because each gcloud account has a separate email address.  So I'll get this error if I don't switch both:

```
$ kubectl get pods          
Error from server (Forbidden): pods is forbidden: User 
"myemail@email.com" cannot list resource "pods" in API group "" in 
the namespace "default": Required "container.pods.list" permission.
```

Maybe there's a way to setup gcloud to allow both users in each account? 
Otherwise I'd have to switch both account and contexts.

Comment: You can use `kubectx -` to quickly switch back and forth between two contexts

Comment: Oh, so your saying I don't really need to switch gcloud accounts unless i'm actually needing to use gcloud to create gcp resources.  Sorry I guess I had missed this obvious fact.  Your right, it seems just switching with 'kubectx -' works fine.

Comment: So I just remembered why I also switch the gcloud account.  When I switch kubectl contexts, then I get "Forbidden" errors since each account uses separate email addresses.  I'll post my issue above in the original question.

Comment: Ok, i've been burnt by this one again: 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59815412/switching-gcp-accounts-and-contexts-with-gcloud-and-kubectl-is-not-working/59815467#59815467

Comment: I guess I'm not clear why this has to be periodically run.  I don't believe my credentials have changed.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose the quickest way to switch is creating aliases in your ~/.bashrc or ~/.zshrc file:

```
alias k8s.acct1="gcloud config configurations activate acct1; kubectx context1"
alias k8s.acct2="gcloud config configurations activate acct2; kubectx context2"
```

Another really great alternative is to set the KUBECONFIG environment variable within each console window (and you could even build alias shortcuts to quickly set this up for each session).

So in one console window you run:

```
export KUBECONFIG=~/acct1-kubeconfig
```

and in another window you run:

```
export KUBECONFIG=~/acct2-kubeconfig
```

And then suppose you have a OpenShift cluster, you do the same:

```
export KUBECONFIG=~/os-kubeconfig
```

Each console session then has kubectl access to each respective account and cluster.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this happens is kubectx uses `gcloud`'s config-helper to get access tokens for your accounts and then saves those to `.kube/config`. `gcloud` will use the currently configured account, so ultimately the wrong access token is saved.

There's a workaround for this, but it isn't ideal. It's especially tedious if you need to add or remove clusters frequently.

Modify `.kube/config` to add an appropriate `--account whatever@domain.com` to every `cmd-args` line in the file. For example:

```
- name: cluster-name-company-1
  user:
    auth-provider:
      config:
        access-token: ya29.xxx
        cmd-args: config config-helper --format=json --account username@company1.com
        cmd-path: /Users/username/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud
        expiry: "2020-05-10T15:49:33Z"
        expiry-key: '{.credential.token_expiry}'
        token-key: '{.credential.access_token}'
      name: gcp
- name: cluster-name-company-2
  user:
    auth-provider:
      config:
        access-token: ya29.xxx
        cmd-args: config config-helper --format=json --account username@company2.com
        cmd-path: /Users/username/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud
        expiry: "2020-05-10T15:49:33Z"
        expiry-key: '{.credential.token_expiry}'
        token-key: '{.credential.access_token}'
      name: gcp
```